# What author joked that his writing skill came from a magical amulet

Tags: quotes, authors

About 10 years ago I read a great quote from a scifi/fantasy writer. Unfortunately I have forgotten both where I read it and who wrote it, but I would like to find it again.

The quote was, as far as I can remember, something like this:

> One of the questions I often get as a writer is "How can you make so good novels", and the answer is simple, years and years of horrible writing in the most obscure fan-magazines you can imagine. Things so bad I cringe to even think about it now. That was how I built the skills to write the way I do now. Unfortunately people do not accept that explanation and keep asking "But how do you really do it!" So nowadays I answer with "An amulet. A magic amulet with magic runes and enchanted gems. I always wear it and that is the secret of my writing.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: A similar answer from Harlan Ellison ("From Schenectady") was expanded by Vonda McIntyre into "There is a mail-order house for ideas in Schenectady to which writers can subscribe for 5 or 10 or (bargain rate) 25 ideas a month."  https://books.google.dk/books?id=QK6TYg32CocC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq="where+do+you+get+your+ideas"+answer+mail-order&source=bl&ots=9DwSq3ZcZC&sig=ACfU3U0rl55RI0rv26rYYJZ0FB68nJJVdQ&hl=da&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD_4inlp3qAhX8JMUKHdaUCsIQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q="where%20do%20you%20get%20your%20ideas"%20answer%20mail-order&f=false